# Shell globbing without matching files

Tags: shell, wildcards

I frequently make use of shell file name globbing to do things like operate on all of `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`, etc by doing `/dev/sd[a-f]`, however, this relies on there being files on disk that match that pattern.  Today I wanted to run `gitk` on each of `master@{1}`, `master@{2}`, etc, but `gitk master@{[1-5]}` does not work since there are no file names matching that pattern on disk.

How can you get the shell to perform globbing without regard to actual disk files?

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want a command like `fsck /dev/sb[a-f]` (i.e., misspelled `sd`) to *not* fail even though there are no `sb` devices? Or are you saying that you want to be able to generate command arguments like `psusi1`, `psusi2`, `psusi3`, etc., even though there are no such files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do shell globbing without matching files. You need [brace expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion):

```
gitk master@{{1..5}}
```

or:

```
gitk master@{{1,2,3,4,5}}
```

With form `{x..y}`, you need `zsh 2.6-beta4` and later, `bash 3.0` and later, `ksh93r` and later.

`{x,y}` was original in `csh` and copied to Bourne like shell first in `ksh`.

Answer (score 1):

In at least bash you can use ranges, e.g.

```
$ echo gitk master@{{1..5}}
gitk master@{1} master@{2} master@{3} master@{4} master@{5}
```

Obviously the echo is used above just to show what happens.

It works for letters as well:

```
$ echo /dev/sd{x..z}
/dev/sdx /dev/sdy /dev/sdz
```

Note: the is glob matching, and there is regex matching. These are two distinct things. The shell does glob matching. So *Shell regex globbing* is not a thing.